# OneSignal Android Studio Unknown error getting FCM Token

Tags: android, onesignal

i have a problem.
I cannot use OneSignal. I don't know why. I googled the error but nothing helped.

Currently i use Android Studio on Version: 4.2
The newest OneSignal Version: 4.3.4
And also the newest Firebase Version. I created a new Firebase Project and OneSignal Project.

This is the Error:

```
2021-05-25 13:06:37.370 3225-4181/de.kggaming.application E/OneSignal: Unknown error getting FCM Token
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorFCM.getToken(PushRegistratorFCM.java:60)
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.attemptRegistration(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97)
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.access$100(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37)
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/de.kggaming.application/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~37wP-zifceloViDoIaZiLQ==/de.kggaming.application-MT0rnPML9HHvlPgijekxXw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~37wP-zifceloViDoIaZiLQ==/de.kggaming.application-MT0rnPML9HHvlPgijekxXw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorFCM.getToken(PushRegistratorFCM.java:60) 
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.attemptRegistration(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97) 
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.access$100(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37) 
        at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

This is my build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this my App build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.kggaming.application"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
}
```

Here the application class:

```
package de.kggaming.application;

import android.app.Application;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    }
}
```

The app don't have any features. Just a empty activity and this onesignal implementation.

Can you help me to get this thing work?

Thank you!

Best regards,

Gismo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId**

faced a similar issue in my flutter project when trying to initialize the `hypertrack_plugin` which depends on firebase SDK.

[image]

After two day of search fixed with adding this implementation in `android/app/build.gradle`

hope this solution might solve your case too.

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid"
}
```

found the solution from this [Link](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/issues/744)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That worked for me. Now i can build my application with onesignal :)

Comment: @LeonBrenn   Cool, you can accept my answer if its worked.

Comment: @LeonBrenn Yup! Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. This answer saved me!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

The class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId has been deprecated and removed from the latest versions of the aar:

```
com.google.firebase.firebase-iid
```

See [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId).

The OneSignal version that you have in your project expects version 20.x.x of the aar file which still has that class. However, if you include v20.x.x of that aar file you will start getting duplicate class errors with the firebase-messaging:22.0.0 library that you are using.

So, the only solution that I can propose is to update the OneSignal SDK that you are using to the latest version.

Comment: Thank your for your Answer!
Sorry for the late answer.

I tried to update onesignal. Maybe they did not updated their sdk.. I build my app now without onesignal.

Comment: @LeonBrenn can you try the answer with I posted to your Que. & check if that works for you.

Comment: If you are using `firebase-messaging:22.0.0` or newer you must use [OneSignal 3.16.0](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.16.0) or newer.